# Member Function Pointer not quite right

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I have a SpecialisedRedBlackTree class that is templated.

My Month class is not.

In my Month class I have a private member which is an instance of SpecialisedRedBlackTree:

```
SpecialisedRedBlackTree<Day> m_windSpeedTree;
```

As you can see it will take the Day class/object (please correct me on any terms I get wrong).

In my Month class, I have a method passing a method function pointer to this method:

```
bool Month::CompareWindSpeed(Day a, Day b) {
return ( a.GetData(WIND_SPEED_CODE) < b.GetData(WIND_SPEED_CODE)? true : false);
}

bool (Month::*myFuncPtr)(Day, Day);
myFuncPtr = &Month::CompareWindSpeed;
m_windSpeedTree.Insert(dayReading, myFuncPtr);
```

But because I am passing a bool (Day, Day) pointer to a templated class expecting bool (T, T)

T being part of this .... template

```
Error 1 error C2664: 'SpecialisedRedBlackTree<T>::Insert' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'bool (__thiscall Month::* )(Day,Day)' to 'bool (__cdecl *)(T,T)'
```

Any advice?

Comment: What's so special about `SpecialisedRedBlackTree`? What are you trying to accomplish? Perhaps we can suggest a better solution?

Comment: what is the signature of `SpecialisedRedBlackTree::insert` function?

Answer (score 2):

The problem at this point is not that the class is templated, but that you are passing a member-function where a non-member function is expected.

You could:

- make `CompareWindSpeed()` a free function or a static member function
- let `Insert()` take a member function pointer and an instance pointer
- use `tr1::function` or `boost::function` or similar wrappers instead of function pointers

Answer (score 0):

A function of an object is not the same as a normal function in regards to function pointers. You need to store a reference to the object it self and also the function pointer to be able to call it.

For Example a class to store the functior and object pointer:

```
template <class TObj, typename TArg>
class ObjDelegate
{
public:
 typedef void (TObj::*TFunct)(TArg&);

 ObjDelegate(TObj* t, TFunct f)
 {
  m_pObj = t;
  m_pFunct = f;
 }

 virtual void operator()(TArg& a)
 {
  if (m_pObj && m_pFunct)
  {
   (*m_pObj.*m_pFunct)(a);
  }
 }

 TFunct m_pFunct;   // pointer to member function
 TObj* m_pObj;     // pointer to object
};
```

To use it you would do this:

```
ObjDelegate<MyClass, MyParam> objDel = new ObjDelegate(this, MyClass::MyMethod);
```

To trigger the function call:

```
MyParam myParamInstance;
objDel(myParamInstance);
```

Comment: You *cannot* treat it as normal function in a context where an ordinary function pointer is expected. In fact, C++ language provides no means to transform a member function pointer into a freestanding (ordinary) function pointer. It is simply impossible, without using platform-specific hacks. In other words, until the tree interface is changed to accept functors, your solution will not really solve anything.

Comment: Well instead of using a functor he could change to accept a ObjDelegate.